# Show that unions of circles and $(0,0)$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $C_n$ be the circle defined as $x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{n^2}$. Let 
$$X = \{(0,0)\}\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} C_n $$

Show that $X$ is compact.

$X$ is obviously bounded, but how should I show that it is closed? It seems clear that it is, but I'm not sure how I can prove it? Maybe I should consider a continuous function from some compact set that maps to $X$? One possible map would be from $(r,\theta)$ where $r\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ but it's not clear that the map is continuous...

Comment: For closure just show it contains its limit points.

Comment: What definition of compactness are you using?

Comment: It complement is the union of the open "washers" between circles and the exterior of the unit circle. These are all open.

Comment: @Alephnull Finite open cover

Comment: @Alephnull I can see that but how would I prove that?

Comment: The washer is all elements with norm between the radii of the two indicated circles. For each element consider the ball with radius equal to one half the distance to the nearest circle. The exterior of the unit circle is all elements with norm greater than 0. You can draw a similar open ball around each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any sequence $x_k$ in $X$. Then either infinitely many of the $x_k's$ are in one of the $C_n's$ or not. If so, then there is a subsequence of $x_k$ that converges to a point in $C_n$. Otherwise, there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $x_{n_k}\in C_{\phi(k)}$ for some monotone increasing function $\phi$. In this case, $x_{n_k}\rightarrow 0\in X$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Take the function $f(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and then show that the set $\{0\}\cup_{n\geq 1} \{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 4):

If $U = \{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ is an open cover of $X$, let $U_0 \in U$ contain $(0,0)$. Then for all but finitely many $n$, $C_n \subset U_0$. If $R$ is the union of all $C_n$ that are not contained in $U_0$, then as the union of a finite number of compact subspaces $R$ is compact, and there exists a finite subcover of $U$, $U_1 \cup ... \cup U_m \supseteq R$. It follows that $U_0 \cup U_1 \cup ... \cup U_m$ is a finite subcover of $U$ containing $X$. Since $U$ was arbitrary $X$ is compact.